# why functional interface 'selectDSLCompleter' does not contain any abstract method?

Tags: java, functional-interface, mybatis-dynamic-sql

As far as I know, a functional interface in Java must have one (and only one) abstract method. However, the interface named `selectDSLCompleter` in `org.mybatis.dynamic.sql.select` does not have any abstract method, but still works normally.

The interface is defined as below:

```java
package org.mybatis.dynamic.sql.select;

import java.util.function.Function;
import org.mybatis.dynamic.sql.SortSpecification;
import org.mybatis.dynamic.sql.util.Buildable;

@FunctionalInterface
public interface SelectDSLCompleter extends Function<QueryExpressionDSL<SelectModel>, Buildable<SelectModel>> {
    static SelectDSLCompleter allRows(){
        return (c) -> {
            return c;
        };
    }

    static SelectDSLCompleter allRowsOrderedBy(SortSpecification... columns) {
        return (c) -> {
            return c.orderBy(columns);
        };
    }
}
```

And is used as this example:

Method defined in mapper:

```java
default List<Person> select(SelectDSLCompleter completer) {
    return MyBatis3Utils.selectList(this::selectMany, selectList, person, completer);
}
```

Method called in service:

```java
List<Person> allRecords = mapper.select(c -> c);
```

Is there anything I missed?

I searched the question, but found nothing. I'm just wondering how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It **does** contain one abstract method. The one it inherits from `Function<QueryExpressionDSL<SelectModel>, Buildable<SelectModel>>`